# System TypeInitializationException error at static constructor iis reset fixes it

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am getting a Type initializer error after a windows update. When I recycle the app pool it works.
I have a static constructor which calls web config database credentials. Since the application works after iis reset or the app pool recycle it won't be an issue with credentials missing in web.config.

System.TypeInitializationException

Comment: Can you share the stack trace of the exception and the code that throws the exception? Maybe these details are in the Windows Event Viewer

Comment: Maybe debug diag tool is better for you to troubleshoot code issue when it ran on IIS. You can analysis the dump file to know which type initial failed and what caused it.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210